# Adjust which tempalte a page uses with a function?

Tags: functions, templates, page-template, permalinks

I know if I had a page that had a permalink such as `/stories/` then I could create a page in my template called `page-stores.php` and it would load in place of the default `page.php` when that page loaded (see [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy))

What I want to know is if I had that two page templates, maybe `page.php` and `page2.php`, if I could use the `functions.php` file to specify that if a page had a permalink of `/stories/` it would use `page2.php`?

I know there is an option when editing a page to let the end user choose the page template, but in this case I would like to set it specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
add_filter('page_template', 'custom_page_template');

function custom_page_template($template){
  // check your permalink here
  if(get_query_var('pagename') === 'stories')
    return locate_template(array('page2.php', 'page.php')); 

  return $template; 
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but it looks right. Thanks!